# All Ruby documentation offline with yard

Tags: ruby, yard

If I want see documentation on my gems I can do:

```
yard server --gems
```

How can I see the documentation of Ruby's standard library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to

1. download the Ruby code archive and extract it into a directory,
2. run `yardoc *.c` (that will generate the core documentation),
   2a. run `yardoc .` (that will generate the stdlib documentation but will take a lot of time),
3. run `yard server`.

(from http://gnuu.org/2010/10/13/local-copies-of-documentation/)